# Why is AngularJS package for Sublime Text blocking default buffer words in completion?

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3, and I installed the very useful [angularJs](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AngularJS) package which gives great code completion for both JavaScript and HTML files, and I really don't want to disable it, but it stops the default word completion of Sublime Text.

In `Preference->Package Settings->AngularJs` I set the `disable_default_js_completions` option to `false` in both user and default settings, but it still messes with the word completion.

Found other people with the same issue :
https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS-sublime-package/issues/69

The only fix seems to be to install a TernJs package for auto-completion to replace the default functionality.

Comment: Your title is supposed to be a full, proper English sentence describing your problem, not a jumble of words and non-words with a question mark at the end.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - good advice. Martin, maybe something went wrong during that angularJs package installation, take a look at these installation instructions from Dan Wahlin's blog: [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-the-angularjs-package-for-sublime-text)

Comment: If you have a problem with a plugin, you should [file an issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS-sublime-package/issues).

Comment: Sorry for the bad English guys ..

Comment: Posted a community wiki answer to arrive at some answer to this question since no immediate resolution is forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is reported, and you have a temporary solution, i.e., TernJS package installation. I had to install that too in order to see buffer words and such appear in the autocomplete list, it wasn't folding them in even at the lower priority. The completions that show in `Show Completions` now appear after installing TernJS. I don't think there is a known hotfix, I've contributed to the report, we'll need to wait on a bug fix, or just keep using TernJS. You probably want to install Emmet and Better Completion packages if you haven't already, as well. Between those, AngularJS and TernJS packages, you're pretty covered, minus any specialities you require.